IMac 8,1 with ubuntu 22.04: blue pixels everywhere
I used to use my iMac several years ago with Ubuntu. I think an update messed it up. Years later I'm trying to fix it. I have an iMac 8,1 (2008 i believe) with ubuntu 22.04. I had 2 different Kernels and removed the newest. Still getting blue pixels everywhere. Got wifi to work by allowing 3rd party repositories (unrelated). See photos.



Is your system fully updated?

You have blue pixels in the GRUB screen, which appears before the kernel loads. It may be a hardware issue.

Do you know that the iMac used to work flawlessly from an older version of Ubuntu? If so, load it from a live USB (no need to install). Is the issue present there? If it does, then most likely you have a hardware issue. If the issue is absent, then we can rule out hardware issue. Please let us know.
